# Django User Registration Issue

Tags: django, ubuntu, python-2.7, user-registration

Django newbie, running on Ubuntu 12.04, Django 1.3.1 and  apt-get install python-django-registration.

Trying build a demo site to use the user registration module. I followed the steps from http://lightbird.net/dbe/forum3.html. But when I try to access accounts/ or admin/, getting the following error: "name 'registration' is not defined"

I am able to access the admin interface, after commenting out the registration part in urls.py. Any tips to overcome this issue?

Comment: Dont use apt-get to install django-python modules. Instead use `pip install`.

Answer (score 2):

is "registration" in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py?

Comment: Yes. It is added in setting.py

Answer (score 1):

Is django-registration on your `PYTHONPATH`? Also I assume that you did syncdb after adding registration to installed app. If both are true, then try opening a shell prompt with `python manage.py shell` and import something from the registration module and see what error that gives

Comment: Yes. It is in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_registration-0.7.egg-info. From shell, with-out error I did, from registration.models import RegistrationProfile.

Comment: Apart from adding the URL and templates, I didn't do any other coding specifically for registration. Do I need to add any supporting stuff??

Comment: Could you please show the code on whose add/delete the error comes/goes? And also how this is being handled in url.py?